# SwipeListView by 47degree: how to disable closing specific item?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe

**Hello**

i'm using **[SwipeListView by 47degree](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview)** and want to know how to disable **close action** for specific item?
and how to close that item programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/issues/9
There you can see issue. Override getItemViewType() in adapter